# Third party https forwarding?

Tags: ssl, encryption, https

My site currently does not have SSL/https set up. Now I need to implement a functionality so that my mobile app can talk to my server. I need https for that and that route only.

Changing my site to be all https seems too much work for that single route.

In my wild imagination, could there be a third party service that provides an https handler that my mobile app can safely pass information to. The third party service then encrypt these these information using my key, and pass these back to my server using standard http?

What can go wrong with my imagined service above? And does such thing exists already?

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to enable ssl on your entire website. you can enable it for specific pages using .htaccess

try this

If you are familiar with mod_rewrite and regex a little bit, you should have no problems reading these rules -- comments are present explaining what particular rule does. the rest -- regex basics:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# force https for /login.php and /register.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(login|register)\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# don't do anything for images/css/js (leave protocol as is)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ - [NC,L]

# force http for all other URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(login|register)\.php$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

These rules need to be placed in .htaccess in website root folder BEFORE any other rewrite rules (if such present). If placed elsewhere some small tweaking may be required.

They will force HTTPS for /login.php and /register.php, do nothing for images, css styles and JavaScript files (to be precise, for files with those extensions) and will force HTTP for all other URLs

You can easily add other URLs to that list -- just edit existing rule by adding additional file name to the list (the same text in 2 places: 1) to force 2) to exclude)

File names are case-sensitive. So these rules will not work if /LOGIN.php is requested (Apache will not serve it either, as Linux is case-sensitive OS .. so no need to worry much here).

Obvious thing: mod_rewrite should be enabled and .htaccess files needs to be processed by Apache (some website hosting companies disabling them for performance and security reasons).

Comment: i searched on google, theres no such 3rd party service for handling ssl. basically, its anti-security. if you can create one, might be helpful for others but no-one uses such config curently.

Answer (score 0):

There are no TLS forwarding services, and there can never be. The reason is that it would defeat all purposes of TLS.

Basically, TLS guarantees that the client is talking with the server it thinks it is, and that nobody can eavesdrop or tamper with the communication. All these guarantees are lost if the hypothetical TLS proxy forwards the communication to another server in plain text.

Comment: In my question I did specify that the forwarded communication be encrypted though. Therefore what you mentioned in your second paragraphs are covered by my imaginary service.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that configuring TLS involves less work than coming up with and implementing your own cryptographic protocol. If you want to address everything TLS does, you will end up with something pretty much like TLS, except your protocol is nonstandard.